# Issue while applying Patch

Tags: magento2, patches

I am trying to install Magento 2.2 patch on my site.

Showing error like this.

```
root@server www/html# patch -p1 < PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE-2019-03-25-08-43-16.patch
-bash: patch: command not found
```

How to proceed further.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the patch command installed in your server. So you can install it with the following commands.

`sudo apt-get install patch` for ubuntu or

`sudo yum install patch` for centos

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the [patch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1p.html) program on your server. It needs installed based on your current package manager for example.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install patch
```

Be very careful running patches in production, you should be versioning all your changes. :)